# How to update Minibian OS to the latest framework?

Tags: raspbian, update, minibian

As you may know, an update has been recently released for Raspbian Jessie a few days ago. It has nice features, and solves many annoying bugs:

https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/another-update-raspbian/

I'm using Minibian OS, a perfect minimal version of Raspbian OS.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/minibian/

https://minibianpi.wordpress.com/

I wanted to know, is it possible to upgrade Minibian to the latest framework by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Or do I have to wait until the Minibian developer releases an update for it?

Thanks for your help and time.

***Edit 1***

The following are the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http //mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main firmware non-free
deb http //archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ jessie main
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Raspbian repository you can update it now.

If you are using special for Minibian repository you have to wait for Minibian devs to sync this changes.

You can check your repository looking in **/etc/apt/sources.list** file.

Comment: Thanks @Huczu for your answer. I checked the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. You can see its contents in ***Edit 1*** on main topic. Does this mean that I can update it myself, and I don't have to wait for Minibian developers?

Comment: There are Raspbian Jessie official repository. You can update your system right now.

Comment: Thanks again @Huczu for your quick comment. I'll try and report the results here. How can I see which version I'm using now ?

Comment: Version of what? 
System: **cat /etc/debian_version**
Kernel: **uname -a**
Package : **packageName --version**

Comment: I updated the Minibian OS using the above commands. Thanks @Huczu for your help.